# Select a Certain Number of Digits After Decimal (Not Rounding) to Pandas DataFrame Starting From 1st Column - Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I simply wanted to select a certain number of digits (5 digits) after the decimal place for data in a pandas data frame starting from column 1 (python index-0) without rounding

For example, my pandas look like this

```
ids       value1     value2       value3       value4
ex12    0.1345656    0.1345656   0.1345656   0.1345656
ex13    0.1345656    0.1345656   0.1345656   0.1345656
ex14    0.1345656    0.1345656   0.1345656   0.1345656
ex15    0.1345656    0.1345656   0.1345656   0.1345656
```

I wanted it to be transformed into this new resulting data frame:

```
 ids       value1     value2       value3       value4
ex12    0.13456    0.13456   0.13456   0.13456
ex13    0.13456    0.13456   0.13456  0.13456
ex14    0.13456    0.13456   0.13456   0.13456
ex15    0.13456   0.13456   0.13456   0.13456
```

So the first column (ids) should never be touched by the transformation and the effect should be only happening from the next column onwards.

Here is my code attempt in Python:

```
import pandas as pd
data = [['ex12', 0.1345656, 0.1345656, 0.1345656 , 0.1345656], 
        ['ex13', 0.1345656, 0.1345656, 0.1345656 , 0.1345656],
        ['ex14', 0.1345656, 0.1345656, 0.1345656 , 0.1345656],
        ['ex15', 0.1345656, 0.1345656, 0.1345656 , 0.1345656]
       ]
df
ids   values1    value2    value3    value4
0  ex12  0.134566  0.134566  0.134566  0.134566
1  ex13  0.134566  0.134566  0.134566  0.134566
2  ex14  0.134566  0.134566  0.134566  0.134566
3  ex15  0.134566  0.134566  0.134566  0.134566
```

It doesn't work when I converted it to string data type so I can handel them as a string (slice them). however, when I do this, the resulting transformation is on the row-wise and not the column-wise and that operation also doesn't perform the same for the rest of the columns. Is there a way to do this in pandas?

```
df.apply(str).apply(lambda x: x[:12])
ids        0    ex12\n1 
values1     0    0.13456
value2      0    0.13456
value3      0    0.13456
value4      0    0.13456
dtype: object
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one column you may try this

```
(df.value1 * 1e5).astype(int) / 1e5

Out[193]:
0    0.13456
1    0.13456
2    0.13456
3    0.13456
Name: value1, dtype: float64
```

for all columns you may use `apply`

```
df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: (x * 1e5).astype(int) / 1e5)

Out[197]:
    value1   value2   value3   value4
0  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
1  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
2  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
3  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
```

To put back to your dataframe. Use `update`

```
df.update(df.iloc[:,1:].apply(lambda x: (x * 1e5).astype(int) / 1e5))

print(df)

Output:
    ids   value1   value2   value3   value4
0  ex12  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
1  ex13  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
2  ex14  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
3  ex15  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
```

If you want to create a new dataframe, use `join`

```
df_new = df.iloc[:,[0]].join(df.iloc[:,1:]
                               .apply(lambda x: (x * 1e5).astype(int) / 1e5))

Out[210]:
    ids  values1   value2   value3   value4
0  ex12  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
1  ex13  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
2  ex14  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
3  ex15  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456  0.13456
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is great but how can I keep the ids column for the resulting data frame?

Comment: If you don't want to change original `df`, use `join` as in my updated answer to create a new dataframe